# Console outputting error before element has been defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, console, runtime-error

I am getting an error on my console in Google Chrome (latest version) that says

```
%7Bsecimg1%7D:1 GET file:///D:/Uriel%20Enterprise%20Center/Apps/Showcaser%20App/%7Bsecimg1%7D net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

A little digging reveals that its because i have an image element like this:

```
<img src="{secimg1}"/>
```

I have a script that fills in the image src and displays the image on the page.
So what it looks like is javascript is displaying the error too quickly, because a few milliseconds later the image is there on the page.

How can i tell javascript or the console to wait to display that error?

Comment: That's not how it works :) And it's not JS giving you an error, it's the browser. It parsed the HTML, saw that this image had an `src` attribute, and tried to load it. Usually, when lazy-loading an image with JS, one would use `data-src` instead of `src`, and then, a JS script would set the `src`. You could do the same. Can't help you with that part if you don't show the relevant parts of your script, though

Comment: ok thats still hepful thanks!